# Execute function on different scope: Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

So I think it's just not possible, yet I wonder...
is there a way to create a function that works like this?

```js
const someFunction=()=> console.log(a); //printing some ref that is not out of this scope;

const wrappedFn = wrapFnOnScope(someFunction,{a:"Hello World!"});

wrappedFn() // prints Hello World!
```

Comment: You seem to be describing the way the `this` keyword works. Why do you not want it instead?

Comment: What your after can be done, but it's not based on scope.   You just pass the object with call, apply..   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @Keith - If we consider the _context of execution_ defines the meaning of `this` as belonging to a lexical context - it can literally be interpreted as a scope thing.

Comment: @RandyCasburn  Sorry, not sure what your on about.  scope is scope, and has nothing to do with `this`.

Comment: `const wrappedFn = console.log.bind(console, {a:"hello"});` is somewhat close

Comment: Yep, I'd have to define the function as `()=>console.log(this.a)`,  but that's not what I want.

Comment: @keith - [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) is defined as the current context of execution - the value of [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#value) is the current execution context - they are intrinsically linked.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, thanks, but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed impossible. JavaScript has lexical scope, which means the scope of the variables in your closure depends (only) on where you did define the function. It is not possible to change this afterwards.

If you want late binding, you need to use parameters in JavaScript. It might be

```
const someFunction = (obj) => console.log(obj.a);
someFunction({a: 'Hello World'});
// or
const wrappedFunction = () => someFunction({a: 'Hello World'});
const wrappedFunction = someFunction.bind(undefined, {a: 'Hello World'});
```

or using the implicit zeroth parameter `this`:

```
function someFunction() { console.log(this.a); }
someFunction.call({a: 'Hello World'});
// or
const wrappedFunction = () => someFunction.call({a: 'Hello World'});
const wrappedFunction = someFunction.bind({a: 'Hello World'});
```

If you insist on referring to an `a` variable in the `someFunction`, use destructuring

```
const someFunction = ({a}) => console.log(a);
function someFunction() { const {a} = this; console.log(a); }
```

or even the dreaded `with` statement (bad idea!), but ultimately you must do this inside the `someFunction`. There is no magic `wrapFnOnScope`.

Comment: I assumed so, but had to ask anyway

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be conflating *variables* and *properties*. A variable is a temporary name given to a value in the code. A property is a key-value pair stored inside an object.

If you want to create a function which simply extracts a certain property from an object, you can just do it like so:

```
const bird = { wings: 2, color: "red" };
const getColor = value => value.color;
const birdColor = getColor(bird); // "red"
```

Secondly, you are trying to assign arguments in advance to a function, but only to execute said function later. This can be done by wrapping the function call in an a function without arguments like so:

```
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = 3;

const delayedApplication = () => console.log(a + b + c);
// nothing happened yet
delayedApplication();
// "6" has been logged to the console
```

Comment: I do understand the difference. I know for example that the `with` keyword somehow messes with the scope. `with({a: "Hello world"}){console.log(a)}` (prints `Hello world`)

Comment: The `with` statement adds an object's properties to the current scope as if they were variables, but it is a very bad idea likely to cause a lot of confusion. Most JS programmers will tell you to avoid this keyword at all cost, and not to base your understanding of scope on it.

Comment: That aside, does this answer your question? If not, you might need to clarify it further.